# Почему не отображается separator в tableview - swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Ничего не менял в плане separator`a. Все стоит по дефолту. Но почему-то не отображается. Всвязи с чем такое могло произойти? Если скролить иконки, то видно, как эта разделительная линия появляется и тут же исчезает.[image: вот пример]

Невероятно, но факт - включил scale на 100%  и сепараторы стало видно. Почему так? Если бы я тестировал на настоящем девайсе, то линии бы были?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На настоящем девайсе линии бы были

Answer (score 2):

На настоящем девайсе все будет видно. На симуляторе бывают баги, если масштаб окна не 100% - просто некоторые линии теряются при сжатии.